# Unable to use path_provider in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am using path provider packager in my Flutter app:

1. I added dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file
2. Run flutter package get [No error here]
3. Import packages

When I am trying to the app. it through the below error:

```
PS C:\android-app\flutter-app-test\file_io> flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on XT1706 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       4.5s
Resolving dependencies...                                   13.6s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider:platformAttrExtractor'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.actionio
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.actaons.AttrExtractor
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lctions.AttrExtractor                                                     deb.actions.AttrExtractor
error in opening zip file --                                          
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.actions.AttrExtractor   
> error in opening zip file
```

Comment: What Flutter version? Did you try `flutter clean`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `Dart version 2.0.0-dev.63.0.flutter-4c9689c1d2`

Comment: with `flutter clean` still have same problem.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Perhaps someone else.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer :) no problem. We will find out the solution.

Comment: Seems you have a newer flutter version than the master branch (maybe beta?). Try downgrading it with `flutter channel master`.

Comment: @Bostrot Still with the same problem.

Comment: Fixed. The problem was not for flutter. its for `compileSdkVersion` which was set 27 in my packages build.gradle.

Comment: Now one more issue occured. Everytime I create a new project default `compileSdkVersion` set for 27 which cause problem. so how I can set it default to 26 in my build.gradle (android/app).

Comment: @prashant.fepale After generating a new Flutter app, just edit your build.gradle. What's the big deal? Creating a new project is a relatively uncommon thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your pubspec.yaml file Add path_provider as a dependencies

```
sependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider:
```

and save it
while importing the file use

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```